# Twitter Application-Only Authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, web, xmlhttprequest, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to access the twitter API using a plain old XMLHttpRequest. And it's not working. I've tried the obvious things (refreshing my credentials, etc).

Any ideas? Does Twitter not allow client-side API access???

```
function getAccessToken () {
    var secret = encodeURI("xxx");
    var key = encodeURI("yyy");
    var keyAndSecret = key + ":" + secret;
    var encoded = btoa(keyAndSecret);

    var authRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    authRequest.open("POST", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token");
    authRequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
    authRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    authRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (authRequest.readyState == 4) {
            var accessToken = JSON.parse(authRequest.response);
            console.log("access token:", accessToken);
        }
    }           
    authRequest.send("grant_type=client_credentials");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar problem, with the following being returned:

```
       code: 170,
       message: 'Missing required parameter: grant_type',
       label: 'forbidden_missing_parameter'
```

But fixed it by moving the post data to its own var and then setting the content-length with that var

```
var postData = "grant_type=client_credentials";
...
authRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", postData.length);
...
authRequest.send(postData);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those referencing this later, looks like the issue may have been the encoding scheme. I used https://www.base64encode.org/ to encode the consumer key/secret and the request went through (was previously getting 403's thrown in my face).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).